# Why can't I edit the Inbox rules of my Outlook.com mail?

Tags: outlook.com

I created some inbox rules in my **Outlook.com** mail and they're working fine, but I get this error when I try to open/edit them:

> There was a problem loading your inbox rules. Please try again or click here to report the problem.

I have found only information for Microsoft Exchange or mail applications in desktop versions, but I always access my account on the web.

P.D. I already "reported the problem".

Comment: Is this for the desktop client or for outlook.com?  If it's the former, it is off-topic here.  [SU] is the correct place for questions about installed applications.

Comment: Did you try reporting the problem? Not much anyone can tell you if it's a bug on Outlook.com's side.